# How to trigger Adobe flash player setting privacy panel from flash?

Tags: flash, privacy, setting

Anyone know how to trigger  Adobe flash player setting privacy panel from flash ? 
Here is the example. There is a "click here" , and when clicked it trigger the panel to show up.
http://chatroulette.com/

THank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

For the default panel:

`Security.showSettings(SecurityPanel.DEFAULT);`

The other options are listed on the [SecurityPanel LiveDocs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/SecurityPanel.html).